# How to sort an integer array in-place in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

how can one sort an integer array (**not** a list) in-place in Python 2.6?  Is there a suitable function in one of the standard libraries?

In other words, I'm looking for a function that would do something like this:

```
>>> a = array.array('i', [1, 3, 2])
>>> some_function(a)
>>> a
array('i', [1, 2, 3])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why have you ruled out using a list?  Did you profile and find it lacking?  If you must use an array and need it sorted, I suggest using numpy, which has a sort method for arrays.

Comment: @Steven Yes, I have profiled it.  I'm working on large collections of integers that barely fit in RAM.  Lists of integers are at least 3 times larger than arrays of integers, so I cannot use them.  Could you (or anyone else) point to a relevant function in SciPy/NumPy?

Comment: Start at http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.sort.html.  Note that the default sort returns a copy, but `ndarray.sort` sorts in-place.  (I have no experience with SciPy/NumPy, but do know that it is well respected and highly optimized.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, you can't do it with `array.array`, but you can with `numpy.array`:

```
In [3]: a = numpy.array([0,1,3,2], dtype=numpy.int)

In [4]: a.sort()

In [5]: a
Out[5]: array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Or you can convert directly from an `array.array` if you have that already:

```
a = array.array('i', [1, 3, 2])
a = numpy.array(a)
```

Comment: And this appears to be an in-place sort.  Good answer.

Answer (score 2):

@steven mentioned numpy.

```
Copies vs. in-place operation
-----------------------------
Most of the functions in `numpy` return a copy of the array argument
(e.g., `sort`).  In-place versions of these functions are often
available as array methods, i.e. ``x = np.array([1,2,3]); x.sort()``.
Exceptions to this rule are documented.
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [array docs](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html), I don't see a method for sorting.  I think the following is about as close as you can get using standard functions, although it is really clobbering the old object with a new one with the same name:

```
import array
a = array.array('i', [1,3,2])
a = array.array('i', sorted(a))
```

Or, you could write your own.

With the extra information from the comments that you're maxing out memory, this seems inapplicable for your situation; the numpy solution is the way to go.  However, I'll leave this up for reference.