# Why doesn’t 'array' have an in-place sort like list does?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, sorting

Why doesn’t the `array` class have a `.sort()`? I don't know how to sort an array directly.

The class `array.array` is a packed list which looks like a C array.
I want to use it because only numbers are needed in my case, but I need to be able to sort it. Is there some way to do that efficiently?

Comment: Maybe numpy is appropriate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540148/how-to-sort-an-integer-array-in-place-in-python

Comment: @Ryan it't a good idea,but I still wonder why array.array() hasn't .sort(),

Comment: @Ryan , an array which can compactly represent an array of basic values, that means no py_object,just new int[],short[] or something else,it can be fast.if you want sort,just call qsort() in C. so I'm ……confused

Comment: Yeah, I don’t know why it doesn’t.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see a justification why this is missing, and this is really against the *batteries included* philosophy of Python. A sort function with a `key` argument would be really helpful to sort arrays of indices pointing to something else.

To sort an array `a` you could of course do:

```
a = array.array("L", sorted(a))
```

but that would not be *in place* and would cost quite some memory and runtime, converting the array to a list and back to an array.

Answer (score -7):

A list is a data structure that has characteristics which make it easy to do some things. An array is a very well understood standard data structure and isn't optimized for sorting. An array is basically a standard way of storing the product of sets of data. There hasn't ever been a notion of sorting it.

Comment: *“A list is a data structure that has characteristics which make it easy to do some things.”* That’s not very specific. *“An array is a very well understood standard data structure and isn't optimized for sorting.”* What. *“An array is basically a standard way of storing the product of sets of data. There hasn't ever been a notion of sorting it.”* What.

Comment: I thank you for the first bit as it is constructive. However I'm afraid you'll have to be more specific for the second complaint. An array is a standard data structure.

Comment: Specifically: “isn’t optimized for sorting” was the part I took issue with. There are tons of algorithms for sorting sequences with constant-time random read and write, i.e. arrays. Maybe you’re talking about a different kind of array with a definition closer to “a standard way of storing the product of sets of data”? array.array (what the question seems to be about) is just a packed list, though.

Comment: But again an array is a standard variable that takes an natural number or Cartesian product of them and out puts or maps to a some other object. Any implementation typically must produce this functionality to be what we think of when we think "array". Nothing further is required.

Comment: I said “sequences with constant-time random read and write”, not “constant-time sorting”. The question is about Python’s `array` class, which has constant-time random access. That means sorting it is no slower than sorting a list, and whatever you’re talking about – some structure that “isn’t optimized for sorting” and which, even, there “hasn’t ever been a notion of sorting” – has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Also in the software world and in reality, doing more than what is asked has serious consequences and costs, but you didn't think of that did you. To you loading a variable from a group always having same size means it's being done in constant time.

Comment: Are you claiming `array.array` *doesn’t* have constant-time random access?

Comment: Just to be clear: A python `list` is an array of values, it has constant time random access. Just like a Python `array`. There is no difference between them. The question why `array`has no sort function is completely valid.

Comment: "An array is a very well understood standard data structure and isn't optimized for sorting." What? Plain wrong.

Comment: "An array is basically a standard way of storing the product of sets of data." Nope. Thats plain wrong. An `array` in python is a linear sequence of integer values allowing constant time random access. This has nothing to do with products or sets or Cartesian products.